# Selenium IE .click() works inconsistently

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, junit, click

I have the following Problem. I use Selenium 2.42.2 to test our company intranet site. Therefore I implemented an example Testcase with a Testsuite. I test this testcase with Firefox 31 and IE 11. All works fine but some times it seems like the IE doesn't click on some elements. It's very confusing because sometimes it works correctly and sometimes it doens't. However I till now I trief the following solutions without success:

- Check Zoom Level and set it in all possible ways
- set up all possible waits (explicit, implicit, some weird variants)
- use 'sendkeys(\n)' instead of .click()

the only solution which works is to double click. But this call new problems with firefox and if this bug doesn't occur.

Does anyone have a hint or any idea which is the cause for the problem?

Thanks for help upwards.

attached Code:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class SeleniumTest_WD_used extends AbstractSelenium {

    public SeleniumTest_WD_used(RemoteWebDriver d) {
        driver = d;
    }

    private String baseUrl = "company.intranet.site.com";

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void worldClock_autoCity_Test_with_ES() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("some XPath")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("some ID"))).selectByVisibleText("Some Text");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Some Css_Element")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("some XPath")).click();
        RemoteWebElement e1 = (RemoteWebElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("some XPath"));
        Assert.assertEquals("Some Assert", e1.getText());
    }
}
```

and I override the 'findElement' Method for IE and FF driver in the following way (but I also got this bug if I use the standard method):

```
public class FirefoxDriver2_0 extends FirefoxDriver {
private static FirefoxDriver2_0 instance = null;
private long startTime;
private long stopTime;

private FirefoxDriver2_0() {
    super();
}

public static synchronized FirefoxDriver2_0 getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new FirefoxDriver2_0();
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
public RemoteWebElement findElement(By by) {
    return elementSearch(by, FirefoxDriver2_0.getInstance());
}

private RemoteWebElement elementSearch(By by, FirefoxDriver driver) {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    RemoteWebElement helpingElement = null;
    isElementPresent(by);
    try {
        helpingElement = (RemoteWebElement) super.findElement(by);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AllTest.updateLogger("[error] method 'elementSearch' incomplete");
        fail("Test not successfull!");
    } finally {
        stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeWarning(by.toString());
    }
    return helpingElement;
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        super.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeWarning(by.toString());
        AllTest.updateLogger("[main] ERROR\tThe following expression could not be solved: " + by);
        fail("Test not successfull! --> Error: Element not found. Please check the failed XPath's");
        return false;
    }
}

private void timeWarning(String s){
    if(stopTime-startTime > 500){
        AllTest.updateLogger("[main] WARNING\tHigh response-time detected: " + (stopTime-startTime) + " ms [@element: " + s + "]");
    }
}
```

If you need some further Code or Information please ask for it. I got two more relevant classes 1.) a Testsuite which initialize the test and 2.) a abstract class as parent for my testcase.

Comment: Sometimes the wait in selenium struggles. Try to put a sleep 2-5 sec before your click/sendkey action run it 10x and if it works , it's just that selenium tries to do things to fast. Otherwise show us some code and an example perhaps =)

Comment: Okay i'll try it. But I fear that it won't work...
I would give you some Code but the problem is that I test our companies intranet site and this site is not reachable for you. Should I give you some could anyway so that you may gather the structure?

Comment: Just anything you can type like : www.fakecompany.com or something doesn't need to be real in your code ( ' on here '), just if something is wrong in there , that we can point it out

Comment: Okay, I tried the Code from above, with the Thread.sleep inserted... now it seems to work... but this isn't a good solution! Isn't there any solution were I could use a explicit wait or some other workaround... Because with this solution I have to check every peace of Code which the selenium IDE creates either I have to build in a Thread.sleep for every time I call the findElement() method which add up to huge amount of extra time...

Comment: Yea I'm not a huge fan of the implicite/ex waits since if selenium thinks it's loaded, it's done and goes to the next action, and like 40% of the cases it goes to fast for me so I have to use sleep in some cases.

Comment: that's crap:/ if I use Thread.sleep(2000) in the findElement Method and I have nearly 5x calls of this method in each test and I have 1200 tests... the result is more than 3 1/2 hours additional time only waiting for IE to work!? That couldn't be best practice... expecially if I don't have the guaranty that IE works 100% perfectly!

Comment: otherwise if I build this Code-phrase in at the critical points thats ridiculos... The quote of failures which will be implemented only of human reasons would be huge and it's so time consuming too...

Answer (score 0):

Now I got a solution!

As you can see in my question Code I override the findElement method from the FF and IE Driver. This is the key to solve this really annoying problem. Because I found out that IE some times simple doesn't click on some elements (mostly elements which send out ajax requests). I guess this happens because IE doesn't focus on this elements directly. IE is slow and needs more time either you need to double click the element (1. to set focus, 2. to really click). And here comes the solution:

You could Override the findElement method from IE and add a simple By-element to save the requested elements. If now an element couldn't be found by this method because the parent wasn't really clicked you could click the parent in this method again and vóila it works!

For this solution it's really important that you build an own class (e.g. named: InternetExplorerDriver2_0) which is a singleton (to perform the click in the own class) and which overrides the standard findElement method.

(I guess it's clear that in the following tests you have to use your changed IEDriver class instead of the original 'InternetExplorerDriver' class)

Here you could find the Code for the changed IEDriver class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement;

public class InternetExplorerDriver2_0 extends InternetExplorerDriver {

    private static InternetExplorerDriver2_0 instance = null;
    private static DesiredCapabilities caps = null;
    private long startTime;
    private long stopTime;
    private By olderBy;

    private InternetExplorerDriver2_0() {
        super(caps);
    }

    public static synchronized InternetExplorerDriver2_0 getInstance(
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities) {
        if (instance == null) {
            caps = capabilities;
            instance = new InternetExplorerDriver2_0();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteWebElement findElement(By by) {
        return elementSearch(by, InternetExplorerDriver2_0.getInstance(caps));
    }

    private RemoteWebElement elementSearch(By by, InternetExplorerDriver driver) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RemoteWebElement helpingElement = null;
        isElementPresent(by);
        try {
            helpingElement = (RemoteWebElement) super.findElement(by);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[error] method 'elementSearch' incomplete");
            fail("Test not successfull!");
        } finally {
            stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timeWarning(by.toString());
        }
        olderBy = by;
        return helpingElement;
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            super.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e1) {

            //the following lines are the important!!!

            try {
                InternetExplorerDriver2_0.getInstance(caps).findElement(olderBy).click();
                super.findElement(by);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timeWarning(by.toString());
                AllTest.updateLogger("[main] ERROR\tThe following expression could not be solved: " + by);
                fail("Test not successfull! --> Error: Element not found. Please check the failed XPath's");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void timeWarning(String s) {
        if (stopTime - startTime > 500) {
            AllTest.updateLogger("[main] WARNING\tHigh response-time detected: " + (stopTime - startTime) + " ms [@element: " + s + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's not the perfectly clean solution but it's a nice workaround and save so much time!

Comment: This is absolutely **insane**. All you are doing is duplicating a `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: I don't think so because I tried WebDriverWait several times in many ways and it doesn't work.

Also WebDriverWait could only focus on the actual element. But if the parent element wasn't clicked you could wait for hours for the next element and it won't be clickable (in case if the click on the parent element get your element to be clickable). 

This problem couldn't be solved with a WebDriverWait as you only use the standard given ExpectedConditions... please correct me if I'am wrong!

Comment: That is wrong, you are not restricted to the `ExpectedConditions` within a `WebDriverWait`. It is generic enough for you to give it *anything*.

Comment: If you have a better solution for my problem then please add an answer! I know what I implemented isn't the best way but until now I don't get another solution that works!